# Prompt at the bottom of terminal and printout scrolls at the top in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am using Python 3.X and looking for a simplest way to have input at the lowest line and all print information scroll above it.  For example if I have `print("hello world")`, it would print at the top and if I have `name = input("What is your name")`, it would be printed on the last line. It seems like there should be a super simple way to do it without using library like the *rich*.

[image]

Comment: This site is best used once you have a specific problem that you can't figure out around code that you are writing. Your question, instead, reads like "Can someone code this for me" or "Can someone point me towards a tutorial or information on how to code this" which are off-topic for Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

So effectively you want the behavior that would occur when the terminal starts scrolling? Just dump a full screen of newlines when you start your program.

```
print('\n' * 200)
```